# Xamarin.Forms Sizing elements in a WrapLayout

Tags: xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

Current:
[image: current status]
Goal:
[image: goal desired]

Attempting to implement a WrapLayout to allow for dynamic button addition in a clean horizontally adding format, as shown in the 'Goal' picture. However as seen in 'Current', the sizing of the buttons in the WrapLayout are far from ideal.

Have found through simple trial and error that using height and width requests in any of the elements (scrollView, wrapLayout, buttons) result in no change to the button formats.

```
HeightRequest = xx;
WidthRequest = xx;
```

The only way, I've found thus far, to change the sizing of the wrapLayout elements is to add a large amount of children, example:
[image: pic_3]

As displayed, my understanding of how to format WrapLayout children is rather lacking. So, how to format the number of children allowed on each row and how to properly format the children of a WrapLayout?

Current implementation developed following the WrapLayout class shown in the [Xamarin Developer Sample for WrapLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout/)

```
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView {
    Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20),
};
WrapLayout wrapLayout;
wrapLayout = new WrapLayout {
     ColumnSpacing = 12,
};
scrollView.Content = wrapLayout;
wrapLayout.Children.Add(
    new Button
    {
        Text = "9 ° (?)",
        BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
        BorderColor = Color.Black,
    }
);
wrapLayout.Children.Add(
    new Button
    {
        Text = "10.5 ° (?)",
        BackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
        BorderColor = Color.Black,
    }
);
```

Comment: You can either set a HeightRequest, or set the Vertical Options to Start in the Button Children

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Great! This is much closer. See `ColumnSpacing` and `RowSpacing`, but how to set number of columns, number of rows?`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [CollectionView Nuget Package](https://github.com/muak/AiForms.CollectionView)

You can use the GridCollectionView, which is based on the WrapLayout.

There, you can either use:

## UniformGrid

The number of columns arranged in each row is specified. Each column width becomes the width obtained by dividing the row width by that value. This number of columns can be set by PortraitColumns and LandscapeColumns properties.
"

## AutoSpacingGrid

Once a column width is specified, each column is arranged until fitting in each row and adjusted automatically each spacing. A column width can be set by ColumnWidth property and Setting SpacingType property can change how to adjust the spacing.

An Example:

```
<ai:GridCollectionView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" TouchFeedbackColor="Yellow"
        ColumnWidth="100" ColumnHeight="1.0" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ai:ContentCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </ai:ContentCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ai:GridCollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `AiForms.Layout` package:

https://dev.to/muak_x/wraplayout-and-repeatablestacklayout-for-xamarinforms-1dck

here is the sample, and it works as we expected:

```
    <aiforms:WrapLayout Spacing="4" UniformColumns="3" IsSquare="true" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <BoxView Color="Red" />
        <BoxView Color="Blue" />
        <BoxView Color="Green" />
        <BoxView Color="Black" />
        <BoxView Color="Yellow" />
    </aiforms:WrapLayout>
```

[image]

And there is a `RepeatableWrapLayout` with Itemtemplate and ItemsSource Binding.